# Do you need to "unwire" event handlers in ASP.NET webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, delegates, event-handling

Given that all controls in a WebForm are destroyed (by my understanding) at the end of each postback do you need to "unwire" any event handlers you may have wired up? (Assuming you want to stop handling the events and allow GC)

So for example:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do I need to remove this handler?
        btnSubmit.ServerClick += btnSubmit_ServerClick; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlikely.  Your `WebForm1` instance's lifetime ends just after the Unload event, if I recall correctly.  It's not as though there is a continuing reference to your `WebForm1` class after the page is served and cleanup is done.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't have to. They will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make a Web Application (WebForm) once with dynamic controls, I had to "unwire" my events, else the page became slower and slower. the "old" pages that I thought the GC had taken care off, was still around. When I unwired the event in Page_Unload my application no longer kept raising the event for the non-existant pages.

This  has only  happened to me once though, and it was probably due to the dynamic nature of the application.

Just food for thought :)

Answer (score 0):

It's too simplistic to assume a WebForm is short lived - in this example you look fine, but in general you should be careful.

Just today, I happened upon a good example similar to @thmsn where failure to unwire an event handlers in an ASP.NET WebForms application was causing a nasty memory leak.

In this case, a master page used in almost all pages was subscribing to the event of an object in it's Page_Init. The object in question was long-lived and persisted in the ASP.NET Session and the site was configured to use the InProc session store with a 60 minute timeout. Failure to unwire the event handler meant that the object was preventing GC of *all* pages accessed during the session for as long as it survived (at least an hour in each case).

The quick fix was to unwire the event handler in Page_Unload - this example shows that the lifetime of a Page can easily be unwittingly extended beyond it's useful lifetime. I won't get into the use of Session here, although it was far from ideal - and I have seen similar bugs introduced with back references from objects with appropriately longer than Page lifetimes too.

Comment: Having an event handler does not extend the lifetime of the object with the event in any way, it extends the lifetime of the object that has the handler for as long as the object with the event is alive, thus the situation you describe isn't possible.  The object that you have would have to be both referencing the page (rather than the other way around).

Comment: Simple typo - subscribing to the event (not handler) of the object. Corrected. And trust me I have the !dumpheap to prove the leak! Cheers :) Subscribing to the event on the object in session means the object had the reference back to the page, and kept it alive.

Comment: Subscribing an event handler to an event does not result in the object with the handler having a reference to the object that defined the event.  You could have explicitly created such a reference in your case; it's easy enough to do, but it doesn't necessarily happen as a result of the event subscription, which means unsubscribing the event handler also wouldn't remove your problem.  Now if your page instance subscribed an event handler to some other object that was long lived, then *that* would keep the page around for as long as that other object is around, but that's a different situation.

Comment: Please read the answer carefully @Servy, the master page in my example does not have the event, the object in session has the event and the page is subscribing to it. Your second comment is exactly what I am describing

Comment: Please read the question carefully.  It's specifically asking about the case of objects subscribing to the events of the page, not the other way around, so your answer *doesn't apply to the question*.

Comment: Hmm, it really feels like you are splitting hairs for the sake of justifying the downvote. I can't help but feel this is *a useful answer*, especially since the question only (admittedly heavily) *implies* rather than explicitly states the event handlers being wired up are on page controls. Although that's the example in the code comment, it technically doesn't explicitly exclude this scenario, which is still useful to consider in the context - since some observers might conclude there are no unsafe event subscriptions issuable from web pages.